No se alinea el texto con el menu lateral en html y css
Quiero que el texto / la información que voy a poner en mi menu que es de investigación la voy a poner alado del menu quiero porfavor que me ayuden a eliminar que este debajo del menu. Si tambien me explican que no se mueva la barra del menu les agradezco y como puedo añadir la información GRACIAS. <3
La imagen que se observa es como esta y quiero que este alado del menu de las opciones el texto no debajo ayuda porfavor necesito entregar esto en 2 días
[1]: https://i.sstatic.net/2ByZrFM6.png
El código:
    <!DOCTYPE html>
   <html lang="es">
  <head>
   <meta charset="UTF-8" />
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
   <title>Inicio</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/estilos.css" />
  <!-- Comentario -->
  <!-- script conexion con los iconos para el menú-->
  <script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/4754ddb85d.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

  </head>
  <body>

   <nav class="nav">
  <ul class="list">       
    <li class="list__item">
      <div class="list__button">
        <img src="imgmn/bx-wrench.svg" class="list__img">
        <a href="#" class="nav__link--nc"><h1>Soporte Técnico</h1>  </a>
      </div>

      <div class="list__button">
        <img src="imgmn/bxs-dashboard.svg" class="list__img">
        <a href="#" class="nav__link">Inicio</a>
      </div>
      
      <li class="list__item list__item--click">
        <div class="list__button list__button--click">
          <i class="fa-solid fa-1" style="color: #ffffff;" class="list__img"></i>
          <a href="#" class="nav__link">Primer Año</a>
          <img src="imgmn/bx-chevron-right.svg" class="list__arrow">
        </div>

        <ul class="list__show">
          <li class="list__inside">
            <a href="#" class="nav__link nav__link--inside">Trimestre 1</a>
          </li>
          <li class="list__inside">
            <a href="#" class="nav__link nav__link--inside">Trimestre 2</a>
          </li>
          <li class="list__inside">
            <a href="#" class="nav__link nav__link--inside">Trimestre 3</a>
          </li>

        </ul>

      </li>
      <li class="list__item list__item--click">
        <div class="list__button list__button--click">
          <i class="fa-solid fa-2" style="color: #ffffff;" class="list__img"></i>
          <a href="#" class="nav__link">Segundo Año</a>
          <img src="imgmn/bx-chevron-right.svg" class="list__arrow">
        </div>

        <ul class="list__show">
          <li class="list__inside">
            <a href="#" class="nav__link nav__link--inside">Trimestre 1</a>
          </li>
          <li class="list__inside">
            <a href="#" class="nav__link nav__link--inside">Trimestre 2</a>
          </li>
          <li class="list__inside">
            <a href="#" class="nav__link nav__link--inside">Trimestre 3</a>
          </li>

        </ul>

      </li>
      <li class="list__item list__item--click">
        <div class="list__button list__button--click">
          <i class="fa-solid fa-3"  style="color: #ffffff;"class="list__img"></i>
          <a href="#" class="nav__link">Tercer Año</a>
          <img src="imgmn/bx-chevron-right.svg" class="list__arrow">
        </div>

        <ul class="list__show">
          <li class="list__inside">
            <a href="#" class="nav__link nav__link--inside">Trimestre 1</a>
          </li>
          <li class="list__inside">
            <a href="#" class="nav__link nav__link--inside">Trimestre 2</a>
          </li>
          <li class="list__inside">
            <a href="#" class="nav__link nav__link--inside">Trimestre 3</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </li>

      <div class="list__button">
        <img src="imgmn/bx-info-circle.svg" class="list__img">
        <a href="#" class="nav__link">Información</a>
      </div>

      <div class="list__button">
        <img src="imgmn/bxs-contact.svg" class="list__img">
        <a href="#" class="nav__link">Sobre Nosotros</a>
      </div>
     </li>
    </ul>

  </nav>
 <!-- /* ==================================== */ -->
<!-- /* ==============TEXTO=============== */ -->
<!-- /* ====================================*/ -->
 <main class="contenido-principal">  
  <div class="contenido"> 
    <div class="entrada">
      <div class="texto">
        <div><img src="img/ini1.jpeg" width="100" class="foto" ></div>
        <h2>Hola,</h2>
        <h3>Somos  </h3><br>
        <h4>Estudiantes de Informática en la Unidad Educativa  </h4><br>
        <p>Diseñamos esta página junto a la asesoría de nuestra profe 
           con el fin de informar, educar e integrar los contenidos que hay dentro
            de toda la carrera de la Figura Profesional de Informática específicamente 
            en el área de Soporte Técnico </p><br>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="intruccion">
      <h2>Nos da mucho gusto <br>
        tenerte aquí 
        </h2>
        <h4>¿Qué estás buscando? </h4>
        <div><img src="img/ini2.jpg" alt=""></div>
        <p>•    En Inicio volverás a esta página principal de todo el contenido. </p>
        <div><img src="img/ini3.jpg" alt=""></div>
        <p>•    Los contenidos están organizados por trimestres del año, y dentro de cada 
          trimestre se dividen en unidades específicas. Esto permite un acceso más ordenado
          y facilita la búsqueda de información concreta. </p>
        <div><img src="img/ini4.jpg" alt=""></div>
        <p>•    En Información podrás encontrar algunas preguntas con su debida respuesta 
 para poder ayudar y mejorar tus enseñanzas adquiridas. </p>
        <div><img src="img/ini5.jpg" alt=""></div>
        <p>•    En Sobre Nosotros conocerás más de nosotros los creadores de la página web 
</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </main>

  <!-- llama al archivo javascript -->
  <script src="js/script.js"></script>
 <!-- TEXTOO -->
  </body>
 </html>

El css es: }
        /* ==================================== */
       /* ==============MENU=============== */
       /* ====================================*/
       * {
           margin: 0;
           padding: 0;
           /* box-sizing: border-box; */
           /*elimina el subrayado de las páginas*/
           text-decoration: none;

       

       }

       body {
           background: #eaebef;
           font-family: 'Times New Roman';
       }
       
       .nav {
           width: 300px;
       }
       
       .nav__link {
           /* color de las letras */
           color: white;
           display: block;x
           padding: 15px 0;
           text-decoration: none;
       }
       .nav__link--inside {
           border-radius: 6px;
           padding-left: 20px;
           text-align: lef;
       }

       /* agregar comentario con cntrl } */
       /* sirve para que cuando pase el raton cambie de color */
       .nav__link--inside:hover {
           background: #5DADE2;
       }
       
       .list {
           /*fijo*/
           width: 100%;
           /*area visible el navegador*/
           height: 100vh;
           display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    flex-direction: column;
    border-radius: 0 16px 16px 0;
    /* COLOR FONDO DE LA LISTA */
    background: #0061AA;

       }

       .list__item {
    list-style: none;
    width: 100%;
    text-align: center;
    /* que se vea y no el submenu */
    overflow: hidden;
       }

       .list__item--click {
           cursor: pointer;
       }
       
       .list__button {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    gap: 1em;
    width: 70%;
    margin: 0 auto;

       }



       

       .arrow .list__arrow {
    transform: rotate(90deg);
       }

       .list__arrow {
    margin-left: auto;
    transition: transform .3s;
       }

       /* aparece y desaparece el men*/
       .list__show {
    width: 80%;
    margin-left: auto;
    border-left: 2px solid white;
    list-style: none;
    transition: height .4s;
    height: 0;

       }

       /* visualizar encabezado soporte técnico */

       .nav__link--nc {
    /* color de las letras */
    color: white;
    display: block;
    padding: 15px 0;
    text-decoration: none;
    pointer-events: none;
       }

       /* ==================================== */
       /* ==============FIN MENU=============== */
       /* ====================================*/

       main {
           display: flex;
           justify-content: inherit;
    margin-left: 300px;
    padding: 0 10px;
    font-size: 20px;
       }

       .contenido-prinicpal p {
    text-align: justify;
       }

       img {
           width: 100;
       }


Si comprendí bien el problema deberías solo darle los estilos correspondientes al contenedor padre que en este caso seria el body, esto utilizando display flex y dandole la orientacion en fila, después de eso solo asignas el ancho correspondiente al contenedor nav y main para que se acomplen bien dentro del body, de esta manera:


/* ==================================== */


/* ==============MENU=============== */


/* ====================================*/

* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  /* box-sizing: border-box; */
  /*elimina el subrayado de las páginas*/
  text-decoration: none;
}

body {
  display: flex;
  /*SE LE ASIGNA AL BODY LA ORIENTACION EN FILA*/
  flex-direction: row;
  /*ANCHO QUE OCUPARA EL BODY*/
  width: 100%;
  background: #eaebef;
  font-family: 'Times New Roman';
}

.nav {
  /*MODIFICAMOS EL ANCHO DEL MENU A %*/
  width: 20%;
}

.nav__link {
  /* color de las letras */
  color: white;
  display: block;
  x padding: 15px 0;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.nav__link--inside {
  border-radius: 6px;
  padding-left: 20px;
  text-align: lef;
}


/* agregar comentario con cntrl } */


/* sirve para que cuando pase el raton cambie de color */

.nav__link--inside:hover {
  background: #5DADE2;
}

.list {
  /*fijo*/
  width: 100%;
  /*area visible el navegador*/
  height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  flex-direction: column;
  border-radius: 0 16px 16px 0;
  /* COLOR FONDO DE LA LISTA */
  background: #0061AA;
}

.list__item {
  list-style: none;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  /* que se vea y no el submenu */
  overflow: hidden;
}

.list__item--click {
  cursor: pointer;
}

.list__button {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  gap: 1em;
  width: 70%;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.arrow .list__arrow {
  transform: rotate(90deg);
}

.list__arrow {
  margin-left: auto;
  transition: transform .3s;
}


/* aparece y desaparece el men*/

.list__show {
  width: 80%;
  margin-left: auto;
  border-left: 2px solid white;
  list-style: none;
  transition: height .4s;
  height: 0;
}


/* visualizar encabezado soporte técnico */

.nav__link--nc {
  /* color de las letras */
  color: white;
  display: block;
  padding: 15px 0;
  text-decoration: none;
  pointer-events: none;
}


/* ==================================== */


/* ==============FIN MENU=============== */


/* ====================================*/

main {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: inherit;
  padding: 0 10px;
  font-size: 20px;
  /*ASIGNAMOS EL ANCHO DEL MAIN*/
  width: 80%
}

.contenido-prinicpal p {
  text-align: justify;
}

img {
  width: 100;
}
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="es">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8" />
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
  <title>Inicio</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/estilos.css" />
  <!-- Comentario -->
  <!-- script conexion con los iconos para el menú-->
  <script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/4754ddb85d.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

</head>

<body>


  <nav class="nav">
    <ul class="list">
      <li class="list__item">
        <div class="list__button">
          <img src="imgmn/bx-wrench.svg" class="list__img">
          <a href="#" class="nav__link--nc">
            <h1>Soporte Técnico</h1>
          </a>
        </div>

        <div class="list__button">
          <img src="imgmn/bxs-dashboard.svg" class="list__img">
          <a href="#" class="nav__link">Inicio</a>
        </div>

        <li class="list__item list__item--click">
          <div class="list__button list__button--click">
            <i class="fa-solid fa-1" style="color: #ffffff;" class="list__img"></i>
            <a href="#" class="nav__link">Primer Año</a>
            <img src="imgmn/bx-chevron-right.svg" class="list__arrow">
          </div>

          <ul class="list__show">
            <li class="list__inside">
              <a href="#" class="nav__link nav__link--inside">Trimestre 1</a>
            </li>
            <li class="list__inside">
              <a href="#" class="nav__link nav__link--inside">Trimestre 2</a>
            </li>
            <li class="list__inside">
              <a href="#" class="nav__link nav__link--inside">Trimestre 3</a>
            </li>

          </ul>

        </li>
        <li class="list__item list__item--click">
          <div class="list__button list__button--click">
            <i class="fa-solid fa-2" style="color: #ffffff;" class="list__img"></i>
            <a href="#" class="nav__link">Segundo Año</a>
            <img src="imgmn/bx-chevron-right.svg" class="list__arrow">
          </div>

          <ul class="list__show">
            <li class="list__inside">
              <a href="#" class="nav__link nav__link--inside">Trimestre 1</a>
            </li>
            <li class="list__inside">
              <a href="#" class="nav__link nav__link--inside">Trimestre 2</a>
            </li>
            <li class="list__inside">
              <a href="#" class="nav__link nav__link--inside">Trimestre 3</a>
            </li>

          </ul>

        </li>
        <li class="list__item list__item--click">
          <div class="list__button list__button--click">
            <i class="fa-solid fa-3" style="color: #ffffff;" class="list__img"></i>
            <a href="#" class="nav__link">Tercer Año</a>
            <img src="imgmn/bx-chevron-right.svg" class="list__arrow">
          </div>

          <ul class="list__show">
            <li class="list__inside">
              <a href="#" class="nav__link nav__link--inside">Trimestre 1</a>
            </li>
            <li class="list__inside">
              <a href="#" class="nav__link nav__link--inside">Trimestre 2</a>
            </li>
            <li class="list__inside">
              <a href="#" class="nav__link nav__link--inside">Trimestre 3</a>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </li>

        <div class="list__button">
          <img src="imgmn/bx-info-circle.svg" class="list__img">
          <a href="#" class="nav__link">Información</a>
        </div>

        <div class="list__button">
          <img src="imgmn/bxs-contact.svg" class="list__img">
          <a href="#" class="nav__link">Sobre Nosotros</a>
        </div>
      </li>
    </ul>

  </nav>
  <!-- /* ==================================== */ -->
  <!-- /* ==============TEXTO=============== */ -->
  <!-- /* ====================================*/ -->
  <main class="contenido-principal">
    <div class="contenido">
      <div class="entrada">
        <div class="texto">
          <div><img src="img/ini1.jpeg" width="100" class="foto"></div>
          <h2>Hola,</h2>
          <h3>Somos </h3><br>
          <h4>Estudiantes de Informática en la Unidad Educativa </h4><br>
          <p>Diseñamos esta página junto a la asesoría de nuestra profe con el fin de informar, educar e integrar los contenidos que hay dentro de toda la carrera de la Figura Profesional de Informática específicamente en el área de Soporte Técnico </p><br>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="intruccion">
        <h2>Nos da mucho gusto <br> tenerte aquí
        </h2>
        <h4>¿Qué estás buscando? </h4>
        <div><img src="img/ini2.jpg" alt=""></div>
        <p>• En Inicio volverás a esta página principal de todo el contenido. </p>
        <div><img src="img/ini3.jpg" alt=""></div>
        <p>• Los contenidos están organizados por trimestres del año, y dentro de cada trimestre se dividen en unidades específicas. Esto permite un acceso más ordenado y facilita la búsqueda de información concreta. </p>
        <div><img src="img/ini4.jpg" alt=""></div>
        <p>• En Información podrás encontrar algunas preguntas con su debida respuesta para poder ayudar y mejorar tus enseñanzas adquiridas. </p>
        <div><img src="img/ini5.jpg" alt=""></div>
        <p>• En Sobre Nosotros conocerás más de nosotros los creadores de la página web
        </p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </main>
  <!-- llama al archivo javascript -->
  <script src="js/script.js"></script>
  <!-- TEXTOO -->
</body>

</html>



Nota: El ejemplo que te acabo de dar es solo si no va a agregar mas contenido del que acabas de mostrar, de lo contrario deberás agregar mas contenedores (padre) y dentro de ellos encapsular el diferente contenido que quieras agregar, esto con la finalidad de mantener un orden por secciones y puedas controlar los diferentes estilos para cada uno de ellos.

Muchas gracias Antonio no sabes de la que me acabas de salvar gracias por apoyar a la comunidad con tus grandes conocimientos, te puedo molestar con como debo de organizar el texto a poner? eso fue lo unico que no entendi

Si, a lo que me refiero es por ejemplo, si tu quisieras agregar imágenes después del texto, deberías de agregar un nuevo contenedor  y dentro de el las imágenes que pretendes agregar, ademas de encapsular el texto dentro de un contenedor también, esto separaría el contenido del nav quedando. , si observas el contenedor padre ahora es el nav que separa tu contenido y puedes controlar mejor los estilos por separado, disculpa que no edite tu pregunta actual pero perdería el contexto principal.

Puedes revisar mas de este tema aqui o si tienes mas dudas puedes generar una nueva pregunta y la comunidad podrá ayudarte mejor, recuerda, siempre muestra el intento que haz realizado.

Prueba con esto:


* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  /* box-sizing: border-box; */
  /*elimina el subrayado de las páginas*/
  text-decoration: none;
}

body {
  display: flex;
  /*SE LE ASIGNA AL BODY LA ORIENTACION EN FILA*/
  flex-direction: row;
  /*ANCHO QUE OCUPARA EL BODY*/
  width: 100%;
  background: #eaebef;
  font-family: 'Times New Roman';
  max-height: 100vh;
}

.nav {
  /*MODIFICAMOS EL ANCHO DEL MENU A %*/
  width: 20%;
}

.nav__link {
  /* color de las letras */
  color: white;
  display: block;
  padding: 15px 0;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.nav__link--inside {
  border-radius: 6px;
  padding-left: 20px;
  text-align: lef;
}


/* agregar comentario con cntrl } */


/* sirve para que cuando pase el raton cambie de color */

.nav__link--inside:hover {
  background: #5DADE2;
}

.list {
  /*fijo*/
  width: 100%;
  /*area visible el navegador*/
  height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  flex-direction: column;
  border-radius: 0 16px 16px 0;
  /* COLOR FONDO DE LA LISTA */
  background: #0061AA;
}

.list__item {
  list-style: none;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  /* que se vea y no el submenu */
  overflow: hidden;
}

.list__item--click {
  cursor: pointer;
}

.list__button {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  gap: 1em;
  width: 70%;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.arrow .list__arrow {
  transform: rotate(90deg);
}

.list__arrow {
  margin-left: auto;
  transition: transform .3s;
}


/* aparece y desaparece el men*/

.list__show {
  width: 80%;
  margin-left: auto;
  border-left: 2px solid white;
  list-style: none;
  transition: height .4s;
  height: 0;
}


/* visualizar encabezado soporte técnico */

.nav__link--nc {
  /* color de las letras */
  color: white;
  display: block;
  padding: 15px 0;
  text-decoration: none;
  pointer-events: none;
}


/* ==================================== */


/* ==============FIN MENU=============== */


/* ====================================*/

main {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: inherit;
  padding: 0 10px;
  font-size: 20px;
  overflow-y: auto;
  /*ASIGNAMOS EL ANCHO DEL MAIN*/
  width: 80%
}

.contenido-prinicpal p {
  text-align: justify;
}


img {
  width: 100;
}
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="es">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8" />
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
  <title>Inicio</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/estilos.css" />
  <!-- Comentario -->
  <!-- script conexion con los iconos para el menú-->
  <script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/4754ddb85d.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

</head>

<body>


  <nav class="nav">
    <ul class="list">
      <li class="list__item">
        <div class="list__button">
          <img src="imgmn/bx-wrench.svg" class="list__img">
          <a href="#" class="nav__link--nc">
            <h1>Soporte Técnico</h1>
          </a>
        </div>

        <div class="list__button">
          <img src="imgmn/bxs-dashboard.svg" class="list__img">
          <a href="#" class="nav__link">Inicio</a>
        </div>

        <li class="list__item list__item--click">
          <div class="list__button list__button--click">
            <i class="fa-solid fa-1" style="color: #ffffff;" class="list__img"></i>
            <a href="#" class="nav__link">Primer Año</a>
            <img src="imgmn/bx-chevron-right.svg" class="list__arrow">
          </div>

          <ul class="list__show">
            <li class="list__inside">
              <a href="#" class="nav__link nav__link--inside">Trimestre 1</a>
            </li>
            <li class="list__inside">
              <a href="#" class="nav__link nav__link--inside">Trimestre 2</a>
            </li>
            <li class="list__inside">
              <a href="#" class="nav__link nav__link--inside">Trimestre 3</a>
            </li>

          </ul>

        </li>
        <li class="list__item list__item--click">
          <div class="list__button list__button--click">
            <i class="fa-solid fa-2" style="color: #ffffff;" class="list__img"></i>
            <a href="#" class="nav__link">Segundo Año</a>
            <img src="imgmn/bx-chevron-right.svg" class="list__arrow">
          </div>

          <ul class="list__show">
            <li class="list__inside">
              <a href="#" class="nav__link nav__link--inside">Trimestre 1</a>
            </li>
            <li class="list__inside">
              <a href="#" class="nav__link nav__link--inside">Trimestre 2</a>
            </li>
            <li class="list__inside">
              <a href="#" class="nav__link nav__link--inside">Trimestre 3</a>
            </li>

          </ul>

        </li>
        <li class="list__item list__item--click">
          <div class="list__button list__button--click">
            <i class="fa-solid fa-3" style="color: #ffffff;" class="list__img"></i>
            <a href="#" class="nav__link">Tercer Año</a>
            <img src="imgmn/bx-chevron-right.svg" class="list__arrow">
          </div>

          <ul class="list__show">
            <li class="list__inside">
              <a href="#" class="nav__link nav__link--inside">Trimestre 1</a>
            </li>
            <li class="list__inside">
              <a href="#" class="nav__link nav__link--inside">Trimestre 2</a>
            </li>
            <li class="list__inside">
              <a href="#" class="nav__link nav__link--inside">Trimestre 3</a>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </li>

        <div class="list__button">
          <img src="imgmn/bx-info-circle.svg" class="list__img">
          <a href="#" class="nav__link">Información</a>
        </div>

        <div class="list__button">
          <img src="imgmn/bxs-contact.svg" class="list__img">
          <a href="#" class="nav__link">Sobre Nosotros</a>
        </div>
      </li>
    </ul>

  </nav>
  <!-- /* ==================================== */ -->
  <!-- /* ==============TEXTO=============== */ -->
  <!-- /* ====================================*/ -->
  <main class="contenido-principal">
    <div class="contenido">
      <div class="entrada">
        <div class="texto">
          <div><img src="img/ini1.jpeg" width="100" class="foto"></div>
          <h2>Hola,</h2>
          <h3>Somos </h3><br>
          <h4>Estudiantes de Informática en la Unidad Educativa </h4><br>
          <p>Diseñamos esta página junto a la asesoría de nuestra profe con el fin de informar, educar e integrar los contenidos que hay dentro de toda la carrera de la Figura Profesional de Informática específicamente en el área de Soporte Técnico </p><br>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="intruccion">
        <h2>Nos da mucho gusto <br> tenerte aquí
        </h2>
        <h4>¿Qué estás buscando? </h4>
        <div><img src="img/ini2.jpg" alt=""></div>
        <p>• En Inicio volverás a esta página principal de todo el contenido. </p>
        <div><img src="img/ini3.jpg" alt=""></div>
        <p>• Los contenidos están organizados por trimestres del año, y dentro de cada trimestre se dividen en unidades específicas. Esto permite un acceso más ordenado y facilita la búsqueda de información concreta. </p>
        <div><img src="img/ini4.jpg" alt=""></div>
        <p>• En Información podrás encontrar algunas preguntas con su debida respuesta para poder ayudar y mejorar tus enseñanzas adquiridas. </p>
        <div><img src="img/ini5.jpg" alt=""></div>
        <p>• En Sobre Nosotros conocerás más de nosotros los creadores de la página web
        </p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </main>
  <!-- llama al archivo javascript -->
  <script src="js/script.js"></script>
  <!-- TEXTOO -->
</body>

</html>



Así mantienes el navegador lateral inmóvil y solo mueves el contenido del lado derecho.
